# How to get Long-lived Access Token for App to Write on Facebook Page?

Tags: facebook, publish, facebook-wall

Digging around for several days to get my PHP app write on facebook fan page and got almost crazy.

1. Already given my app manage_page permission for a particular facebook page.
2. Visited

   ```
   h..s//www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=SOME_FALLBACK_URL_TO_GET_ACCESS_TOKEN_FROM_URL&response_type=token&scope=manage_pages,publish_stream
   ```
3. Copied access token from result of previous step
4. Visited

   ```
   h..s//graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=COPIED_ACCESS_TOKEN
   ```
5. Got the result as following:

   ```
   "data": [
       {
            "name": "PAGE_TITLE",
            "access_token":     "SHORT_LIVING_ACCESS_TOKEN",
            "category": "Local/travel",
            "id": "PAGE_ID_THAT_APP_IS_TO_WRITE_ON_WALL",
            "perms": [
                       "ADMINISTER",
                       "EDIT_PROFILE",
                       "CREATE_CONTENT",
                       "MODERATE_CONTENT",
                       "CREATE_ADS",
                       "BASIC_ADMIN"
                     ]
      },
   ```
6. Copied the `SHORT_LIVING_ACCESS_TOKEN`
7. Visited

   ```
   h..s://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={APP_ID}&client_secret={APP_SECRET}&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token={SHORT_LIVING_ACCESS_TOKEN_FROM_STEP_5}
   ```
8. Getting the error and stuck here:

   ```
   {"error_code":1,"error_msg":"An unknown error occurred"}
   ```

p.s. I correctly replaced `{APP_ID}`, `{APP_SECRET}` where necessary.

Please, help!

Answer (score 2):

You’re doing it the wrong way around, I think. You are getting a short-lived *page* access token and try to prolong that.

What you should do, is get a short-lived *user* access token, prolong **that**, and *then* go get the page access token with the *long-lived* user access token.

*That* process should give you a page access token with no default expiry.

Comment: Once I wrote the post above, I tried the same you explained and it did work. So, you are right, that's a right way.